# Creating a score function in pygame with collisions

Tags: python, function, pygame, sprite

When two sprites collide in my game (the player and the 'key'), I would like for the score variable to increase by 100 points. I have tried many methods but they all do the same thing; when the sprite in in contact with the key, the variables continuously increases. I need it to increase once per collisions. This is just one of the methods I have tried:

```
def key_collect():
    global key_score
    global score_rect
    k_rect = pygame.draw.rect(SURF, (0,0,0), (k_spritex, k_spritey, 30, 40), 1)
    p_score_rect = pygame.draw.rect(SURF, (0,0,0), (p_spritex, p_spritey, 30, 40), 1)
    if p_score_rect.colliderect(k_rect):
        if score_rect == True:
            key_score = key_score + 100
            return key_score
            score_rect = False
            return score_rect
```

I tried making so the score would increase by 100 if the variable score_rect was True and then make it False, meaning it can no longer increase. I was going to make it so that when the sprites are not in collision, the variable going back to being True again so the process is repeated. Yet, once again it just continuously increases while the sprites remain in contact. I'm really stuck and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the function exits at the line `return key_score` and skips the two lines after that. The keyword `return` always terminates your function on the first encounter.

You can just slightly change your code:

```
def key_collect():
    global key_score
    global score_rect
    k_rect = pygame.draw.rect(SURF, (0,0,0), (k_spritex, k_spritey, 30, 40), 1)
    p_score_rect = pygame.draw.rect(SURF, (0,0,0), (p_spritex, p_spritey, 30, 40), 1)
    if p_score_rect.colliderect(k_rect):
        if score_rect == True:
            key_score = key_score + 100
            score_rect = False
            return key_score, score_rect
    else:
        score_rect = True
        return key_score, score_rect
```

I'm assuming here that you want to return both the `key_score` and `score_rect` variables. Since they are both global, that's not really needed.

Comment: This works with only a slight change to the indent (which I edited) :) Thankyou so so much, I thought I'd have to start all again with my project you've literally saved half my A-level since I didn't know you could return two variables at once, thankyou xD !! Appreciate the help so much

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
def key_collect():
    global key_score
    k_rect = pygame.draw.rect(SURF, (0,0,0), (k_spritex, k_spritey, 30, 40), 1)
    p_score_rect = pygame.draw.rect(SURF, (0,0,0), (p_spritex, p_spritey, 30, 40), 1)
    if p_score_rect.colliderect(k_rect):
        if can_increase == True:
            key_score = key_score + 100
            can_increase = False
            return key_score
    else:
         can_increase = True
```

Comment: Does the same thing as before, just constantly adds 100 :(

Comment: Ok, do something here: move the declaration of the global can_increase out of this function

Comment: No difference unfortunately

Comment: I have changed the code. I think the problem was in the variable not been set to False properly.